# Adding size to dynamic tree from last column

Tags: python, json, tree

I need to create a nested dict structure where the number of children can vary at each level.

[Appending “size” element to last json child element for a sunburst diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416498/appending-size-element-to-last-json-child-element-for-a-sunburst-diagram)
Tree creation is covered in this question, except that i need the size to be picked up from the last column.

Given my labels repeat between levels and each level can have the same label "abc" as a terminal one, as well as a parent to the next level - I modified the code here slightly (to avoid duplicates in a children branch). I am unable to however specify the size, which is stored in the last column and should replace the 1 here in each leaf end. I know that I need to pass the value from the rows to the recursion loop build_leaf, but can't seem to figure how.

[image: Sample data]

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import json

def ctree():
    return defaultdict(ctree)


def build_leaf(name, leaf):        
    if len(name)==0:
        res={"name":"last node"}
        res['size']=1
    else:
        res = {"name": name}

        # add children node if the leaf actually has any children
        if len(leaf.keys())>0:
            res["children"] = [build_leaf(k, v) for k, v in leaf.items()]
        else:
            res['size'] = 1

    return res

def main():
    tree = ctree()
    # NOTE: you need to have test.csv file as neighbor to this file
    with open('./inpfile.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        header = next(reader)  # read the header row        
        i=0
        for row in reader:
            # usage of python magic to construct dynamic tree structure and
            # basically grouping csv values under their parents
            leaf = tree[row[0]]
            size=row[-1]

            for value in row[1:-1]:
                leaf = leaf[value]

    # building a custom tree structure
    res = []

    for name, leaf in tree.items():
        res.append(build_leaf(name, leaf))

    # printing results into the terminal
    print(json.dumps(res, indent=2))
    with open('paths.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(res, fp)


main()
```

The final output for the data mentioned should look something like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "A2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "A1",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "A2",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "A3",
                    "size": 80
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "A3",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "A2",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "A3",
                    "size": 169
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "exit site",
                "size": 764
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "A6",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "A3",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "exit site",
                    "size": 127
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "exit site",
            "size": 576
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles across the same problem - I could get it to work, by creating another recursive loop to retrieve size from the nested leaf (thanks to Douglas for the help).

```
def ctree():
    return defaultdict(ctree)

def get_size(leaf1):
    for k,v in leaf1.items():
        if k=="size":
            return v
        else:
            return get_size(v)


def build_leaf(name, leaf):

    if len(name)==0:
        res={"name":"exit site"}
        res['size']=int(get_size(leaf))

    else:
        res = {"name": name}

        # add children node if the leaf actually has any children
        if not leaf["size"]:
            res["children"] = [build_leaf(k, v) for k, v in leaf.items() if not k == "size" ]
        else:
            res['size'] = int(get_size(leaf))

    return res

def make_json(inpfile,outjson):
    tree = ctree()
    # NOTE: you need to have test.csv file as neighbor to this file
    with open("./filepath.csv") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        header = next(reader)  # read the header row        

        for row in reader:
            # usage of python magic to construct dynamic tree structure and
            # basically grouping csv values under their parents
            leaf = tree[row[0]]
            size=row[-1]

            for value in row[1:-1]:
                leaf = leaf[value]
            if len(row) < 6:
                leaf["exit site"]["size"]=size
            else:
                leaf["size"]=size

    # building a custom tree structure
    res = []

    for name, leaf in tree.items():
        res.append(build_leaf(name, leaf))

    with open(outjson, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(res, fp)
```